# Boundedness of functions in the Hardy space $H^2(\mathbb H)$

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

Let $F: \mathbb H \to \mathbb C$ be a function in the Hardy space $H^2(\mathbb H)$. In other words, we have
$$\sup_{y>0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |F(x+iy)|^2 \, dx < \infty.$$
Let $f(x) = \lim_{y \downarrow 0} F(x+iy)$ be the boundary function. Such limit exists a.e. in $x$, and we know that $f \in L^2(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$.

What I want is to make $F$ a bounded function on $\mathbb H$, by assuming additional condition if necessary. I think boundedness is not a very strong condition, considering the Phragmen-Lindelof principle.

For example, I would like to ask:

1. Is $F$ bounded?
2. If we further assume that $f\in L^\infty(\mathbb R, \mathbb C)$, then is $F$ bounded?
3. If we further assume that $f(x) \leq \frac{C}{(1+|x|)^\alpha}$ for some constants $C$ and $\alpha$, then is $F$ bounded?

Partial answers or other conditions are also welcome!

Comment: Note that $F$ is represented by the Poisson formula $F(x+iy)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{(x-t)^2+y^2}f(t)dt$ so in particular $2$ above is easily seen to be satisfied; $1$ is not as there are simple examples like $(z-1)^{-1/4}(z+i)^{-1}$ which is clearly unbounded near $1$ but is in $H^2$ by simple majorizations as for large $y$ the $2$ mean square is $O (y^{-5/4+\epsilon})$ while for $y$ near zero it is $O(1)+O(y^{1/2})$

Comment: @conrad Thanks for your answer! The key idea was the Poisson formula. If you write this comment into an answer, I will accept it.